# Drag and drop from QToolBar to QGraphicsView is not working as expected

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, qgraphicsview, qtoolbar

I am working on a project using `Qt C++` . I have a `QToolBar` which contains some `QButton`s (read as `QAction`) and a `QGraphicsView` (the whole bottom part).
It looks like this.

[image]

Now,  I want to drag a `QButton` (read as `QAction`) from the `QToolBar` into central window (which actually is `QGraphicsView`) of my application.

Till now I have written the following `SLOT` for corresponding `QAction` to enable dragging and dropping.

```
/* Send_Message is one of the actions */
void CTestBuilderApp::on_actionSend_Message_triggered()
{    
    QByteArray itemData;    
    QDataStream dataStream(&itemData, QIODevice::WriteOnly);    
    emit selectionState(None); 

    dataStream << "Send Message";    

    QMimeData *mimeData = new QMimeData;    
    mimeData->setData("application/x-dnditemdata", itemData);    

    QDrag *drag = new QDrag(this);    
    drag->setMimeData(mimeData);    
    drag->setPixmap(ui->ToolBox->actions().at->icon().pixmap(48,48));    
    drag->exec(Qt::CopyAction, Qt::CopyAction);    
    qDebug()<<"drag complete";
}
```

But, as this `SLOT` is being called only when I am `click`ing on the `QAction`, I am not getting the proper effect of Drag and Drop. When I am clicking the button, only then the dragging is starting. One click on the `QAction` and then another click on `QGraphicsView` is doing the job, but it's not what it's supposed to be for drag & drop. It's not starting on pressing and then dragging.

Is there any way out to make this code work? I am searching for some `SLOT` that get called as soon as I press on the `QAction` i.e. it does not wait for Mouse Release to work.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the QGraphicsView slots (so you need to subclass it):

```
void GraphicsView::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *p_event)
{
    p_event->acceptProposedAction();
}

void GraphicsView::dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *p_event)
{
    p_event->acceptProposedAction();
}

void GraphicsView::dropEvent(QDropEvent *p_event)
{
    p_event->acceptProposedAction();
}
```

In your QGraphicsView constructor you have to accept the drops:

```
setAcceptDrops(true);
```

In all the slots you have to accept the action to allow the flow:

```
enter -> move -> drop
```